# What is the best way to join lambda expression

Tags: lambda, asp.net-mvc-5

Maybe its a wrong question but is it possible to join 2 lambada expression in single @Html.DisplayFor. Or do I have to use different mnethod?

**I have a Controller/index page as:**

```
// GET: PAYMENT
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var pAYMENT = db.PAYMENT.Include(p => p.CUSTOMERS).Include(p => p.LOCATION);
    return View(pAYMENT.ToList());
}
```

**in cshtml:**

```
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CUSTOMERS.CustomerName)
        </td>
```

What I want is that, I have to show both CustomerName and CustomerSurname in single @Html.DisplayFor. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DisplayFor` needs a property to map to, so a concatenation is impossible.

**Method 1:**

You might expose a read-only property FullName on your model, which then returns the concatenation:

```
   public string FullName
   {
    get
    {
     return User.CustomerName + " " + User.CustomerSurName;
    }
   }
```

and then use that in your DisplayFor.

```
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.FullName);
```

**Method 2:**

```
        var FullName= item.CustomerName + item.User.CustomerSurName;
        <tr> 
           <td> 
                @Html.Display(FullName) 
           </td> 
        </tr>
```

**Method 3:**

```
       <tr><td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerName ) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerSurName)</td></tr>
```

Comment: Thank you Vinoth. If I use in my model does it effect my database? Becase ın my model Customer shows in int id. It is a FK.

Comment: No it wont effect the database. until you use `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges ` in `Database.SetInitializer`

Answer (score 1):

A quick-n-easy fix (assuming you want to render the `CustomerName` and `CustomerSurname` as plain literals) would be to just write this:

```
<td>
  @Model.CustomerName @Model.CustomerSurname
</td>
```

This has a drawback, though, namely, if you use custom display templates (for example, which render the text in some sort of consistently stlyes `<span>`'s or something like that, you lose the advantage of centralizing the display styles. (Read on custom editor/display templates for finding out what this means.)

A more elegant, and a generally more preferable option is to use viewmodels, which contain data in the form you need it, rather than passing a db entity to your view, which is a bad practice.

```
public class PaymentViewModel
{
    public String CustomerName { get; set; }
    public String CustomerSurname { get; set; }
    public String CustomerFullName { get { return String.Format("{0} {1}", CustomerName, CustomerSurname); } }
    // ... more properties
}
```

Comment: Thank you. At the moment I will stick first option. I have to read more about ViewModel.